# Python: Regular Expression to filter string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am having an input string:

```
internal_key="apachesolr" pid="2822" category="known" display_name="Apache Solr" vendor="The Apache Software Foundation"
```

I have to filter the display_name, and that name can be anything.

the output should be:

Apache Solr

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str="""internal_key="apachesolr" pid="2822" category="known" display_name="Apache Solr" vendor="The Apache Software Foundation"""    
re.findall("display_name=\"([^\"]*)", mystr)
```